# Style the title of a javafx TitledPane with css

Tags: css, javafx-8

I am trying to alter the look of the title on a TitledPane by using css, all the styles I assign are applied, except for the color of the text.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
.titled-pane > .title
{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.5);
    -fx-border-color: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.8);
    -fx-font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: WHITE;
}
```

I also tried

```
.titled-pane > .title > .text
{
    -fx-text-fill: WHITE;
}
```

with no success

Comment: Sometimes the proper css property is -fx-fill. Perhaps this is one of those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane) claims the `.text` node is a `Labeled`, it is actually a `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LabeledText`, which is a subclass of `Text`.

A `Text` has no `-fx-text-fill` property, but has a `-fx-fill` property (because it is a subclass of [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape)). Consequently, the correct CSS is

```css
.titled-pane > .title
{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.5);
    -fx-border-color: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.8);
    -fx-font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}


.titled-pane > .title > .text
{
    -fx-fill: WHITE;
}
```

[Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) can be very useful in figuring out these issues.

Comment: yesssssss, my hero !!! So the documentation is actually a bit frelled up here? Good to know and thanks for the tip with Scenic View, I will check it out.

Comment: the Scenic View tip is gold! Thanks a lot!